# How to upload files to a mounted network folder using paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, carrierwave

I have a folder `myfiles` under the a mounted network drive.

I can access it using `\\networkdrive\myfiles` in the Windows explorer and I have full access to it.

I specify this in my model:

```
has_attached_file :file,
                    :path => "//networkdrive/myfiles/:id/:basename.:extension",
                    :storage => :filesystem
```

but it does not save the file to the location I specify.

Any idea what's wrong here?